# How can I make div not disappear when buttons are clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome, fade

So I have a page that fades in when a button is pressed, and the page has 3 font-awesome icons on it. And when you click anywhere on the page it fades it fades the page out. When you click the font-awesome icons on the page it takes you to another page. But the problem is that the page fades out when you click the buttons. I want it to only fade out when you click anywhere except on the font-awesome icons.

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('#fadeContent').click(function(){
    var bodyContent = $('#bodyContent')
    bodyContent.fadeIn(400);
    bodyContent.click(function() {
      $(this).fadeOut(400);
    })
  });
  
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  z-index: -100;
  background-color:black;
}

#bodyContent{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#454545;
  z-index: 100;
}

.fa-times{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-top: 1.5%;
}

.fa-twitter,
.fa-github,
.fa-steam {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    padding: .5em;
    border: 5px solid white;
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    margin-right: 1.5%;
}

.fa-times:hover {
    color: #f06262;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-twitter:hover,
.fa-github:hover,
.fa-steam:hover {
    background-color: #1dd2e2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.home {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.about {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 37%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.projects {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 54%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.contact {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 71%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.home:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.about:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.projects:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.contact:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Home</title>
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Play" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://rawgit.com/fralec/elegantShareJS/master/css/elegant.css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>  
<body>

    <button class="home">Home</button>
    <button class="about">About</button>
    <button class="projects">Projects</button>
    <button id="fadeContent" class="contact">Contact</button>

      <div id="bodyContent">
           <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           <a href="https://twitter.com/LukielD" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
           <a href="https://github.com/LukieID" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
           <a href="steamcommunity.com/id/LukieID" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-steam" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
    
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/elegant.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/transition.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, the z-index for #bodycontent is 100.  That means its on top of the buttons.  If this is important for another reason, make the buttons z-index 101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the clicked element has the font awesome class.  If not, do the fade:

```
bodyContent.click(function(e) {
  if(!$(e.target).hasClass('fa')) {
    $(this).fadeOut(400);
  }
})
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('#fadeContent').click(function() {
    var bodyContent = $('#bodyContent')
    bodyContent.fadeIn(400);
    
    bodyContent.click(function(e) {
      if(!$(e.target).hasClass('fa')) {
        $(this).fadeOut(400);
      }
    })
  });
  
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  z-index: -100;
  background-color:black;
}

#bodyContent{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#454545;
  z-index: 100;
}

.fa-times{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-top: 1.5%;
}

.fa-twitter,
.fa-github,
.fa-steam {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    padding: .5em;
    border: 5px solid white;
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    margin-right: 1.5%;
}

.fa-times:hover {
    color: #f06262;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-twitter:hover,
.fa-github:hover,
.fa-steam:hover {
    background-color: #1dd2e2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.home {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.about {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 37%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.projects {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 54%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.contact {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 71%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.home:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.about:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.projects:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.contact:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Home</title>
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Play" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://rawgit.com/fralec/elegantShareJS/master/css/elegant.css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>  
<body>

    <button class="home">Home</button>
    <button class="about">About</button>
    <button class="projects">Projects</button>
    <button id="fadeContent" class="contact">Contact</button>

      <div id="bodyContent">
           <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           <a href="https://twitter.com/LukielD" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
           <a href="https://github.com/LukieID" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
           <a href="steamcommunity.com/id/LukieID" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-steam" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
    
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/elegant.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/transition.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should  register click event on each icon and cancel further event handling by calling stopPropagation method.

Exsample:

```
$(".fa").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: That would solve the OP's specific issue, but it would cancel any other click events that those buttons might have.